# Problems to install library

Tags: c, ruby, console

I downloaded an folder on

```
 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/towitoko/towitoko_2.0.7.orig.tar.gz
```

I unzipped it to:

```
 C:\towitoko-2.0.7
```

In the instructions it says:

*The simplest way to compile this package is:*

1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type`
   ./configure' to configure the package for your system.  If you're
    using `csh' on an old version of System V, you might need to type`
   sh ./configure' instead to prevent `csh' from trying to execute`
   configure' itself.

   Running `configure' takes awhile.  While running, it prints some
    messages telling which features it is checking for.
2. Type `make' to compile the package.
3. Optionally, type `make check' to run any self-tests that come with
    the package.
4. Type `make install' to install the programs and any data files and
    documentation.
5. You can remove the program binaries and object files from the
    source code directory by typing `make clean'.  To also remove the
    files that`configure' created (so you can compile the package for
    a different kind of computer), type `make distclean'.  There is
    also a`make maintainer-clean' target, but that is intended mainly
    for the package's developers.  If you use it, you may have to get
    all sorts of other programs in order to regenerate files that came
    with the distribution.

SO i typed in my console:

```
C:\Users\animal>cd C:\towitoko-2.0.7

C:\towitoko-2.0.7>./configure
 The command "." is either fals wrote or couldnt be found.
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is trying to run a "unix" style shell script on a Windows machine. This is highly likely connected with the fact that you downloaded it from a "debian" ftpsite. I'm not familiar with towitoko, so not sure whether it is possible to compile on windows or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick google tells me that the code you are trying to compile is what can be found here: https://github.com/cprados/towitoko-linux
That is definitely a linux driver, and won't work in a  Windows OS without serious work.

I'm not sure if there is a similar product available for Windows.

Comment: Sorry but is it possible to install it with cygwin for example?

Comment: You could get the ./congifure to run, and if you get enough of the source-code for Linux copied to the machine, it may even compile. But the resulting binary will not do anything useful unless it's majorly modified to work in a Windows environment. Code written to be portable (or at least not written to be unportable) is not hard to convert, but driver code is not the kind of code that is possible to write anything other than "unportable", because the driver interfaces are themselves unportable.